# How to get all ids to pouchdb's documents using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, pouchdb

i wanted to know how to get all the ids of a certain database from pouchdb using node.js
this is my try at it but as you can guess it hasn't been working, specifically i need to get all the ids into an array of numbers, only the ids nothing else. Im kind of a beginner to javascript and databases

```
var PouchDB = require('PouchDB');
var db = new PouchDB('mes_iab_db');

db.allDocs({
   include_docs: true,
   attachments: true
 }).then(function (result) {
   console.log(result)
   var new1 = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
   console.log(new1);
   new1.filter(id=>{id=_id;})
 }).catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true,
})
  .then(function (result) {
    if (result.rows && result.rows.length) {
      return result.rows.map(({ doc }) => doc._id);
    }
    return [];
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```